# VMWare software that support snapshots

Tags: virtualization, snapshot

I need to run some VMs But it seems like VMWare Player doesn't support snapshots.

Is there any other free software from VMWare that support snapshoting?

PS: I know that Oracle VirtualBox can do that but I am interested in VMWare products at the moment.

Comment: What is the WMWare of which you speak?

Comment: @JoelCoel sorry, typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes (to your actual question "Is there any other free software from VMWare that support snapshoting?"):

http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html

The hypervisor has been free for quite some time now and supports snapshots.

Now, you are probably wanting a host OS product like VMWare workstation, which isn't free, or Virtualbox, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Just buy Workstation if you need a VMWare product for running VMs with snapshots on a client machine.  The alternative (as far as VMWare products go) is setting up an ESXi host using the free version of that.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: VMWare Player supports one snapshot per Virtual Machine.

However, you can get a full free version of vmware workstation technology preview. It potentially has some bugs but it's free for the next few months:

http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/beta/workstationtp2012

FWIW: I use the tech preview and it works very well.

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  There is a free VMWare product that allows running VMs and supports snapshots.

Comment: I think I am correct, technically. VMWare player supports ONE snapshot (singular) per virtual machine. It was also safe to assume that he wants a desktop application, not something like ESX.